# Passing object to node's Error class returns an unaccessible object

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm returning an `Error` object, to which I pass an object (instead of a simple message):

```
if (err) {
   return myCallback(new Error({
      error_code: 'sample_machine_readable_code', 
      error_message: 'There is an error in the response from the service.', 
      error: err
   }));
}
```

And the result in the console is `[Error: [object Object]]`. I tried accessing its properties both as properties of an array and as an object, but always end up with `undefined`. `JSON.stringify`-ing it returns an empty object `{}`. By "accessing" I mean trying to log the error, f.e. with `console.log(err);` (which ends up in `[object Object]`) or `err.message` or `err.Error`, or `err['Error']`, but these were `undefined`.

I was reading through [Node's Error class docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html) and it seemed like it's okay to pass objects. Am I mistaken? Should I just return a simple custom-constructed object instead of a `new Error`? Like that:

```
if (err) {
       return myCallback({
          error_code: 'sample_machine_readable_code', 
          error_message: 'There is an error in the response from the service.', 
          error: err
       });
    }
```

Cuz I just wanted to use more of what Node offers and to stick to some widely used convention instead of going "my own way".

Comment: How do you log this in the console? By default the error should have a `message` property so that it can read the message

Comment: What works for me is the following: `var error = new Error("There is an error in the response from the service"); error.error = err; error.error_code = "Code"`. Then you can access the message through `error.message` and other properties as well. Can you try that?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin, I went along with this solution. I was wondering between returning a simple, custom object with the error data, and your suggestion. I settled with yours, cuz then I can call `.stack` and other native properties upon the returned error object, without the need of explicitly declaring them. You can write it as an answer, so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you can do, is simply create an instance of `Error` and assign custom properties to it, like this:

```
var error = new Error("There is an error in the response from the service"); 
error.error = err; 
error.error_code = "sample_machine_readable_code"

return myCallback(error);
```