# In Javascript, how can I throw an error that prints an object to the console?

Tags: javascript

The `console.error()` (or `console.log()`) statement has some nice features like variable-length argument lists that print out objects (and arrays):

```
const spaghettio = {sauce: 'arrabiata', cheese: 'gorgonzola'}
console.log(`Uh oh,`, spaghettio)
```

The object is printed out in a way I can expand the keys, which is very handy for large objects:

[image: object formatted by console.log()]

But if I want to throw a real error, I don't have those options. So I usually end up doing this:

```
console.error(`Uh oh`, spaghettio)
throw new Error(`Uh oh: ${spaghettio}`)
```

The `Error` version generally does a crappy job of formatting the objects and arrays:
`Uh oh: [object Object]`. I can do

```
throw new Error(`Uh oh: ${JSON.stringify(spaghettio)}`)
```

But no matter how I slice it it's not as nice as what `console.error` does.

Is there a better way to avoid repeating myself here while still printing out objects to the console?

Comment: why do you need to concatenate the string and the object anyway

Comment: maybe this wil help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35506188/13583510

Comment: You can see the signature of Error constructor in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error
So you may use `new Error ('message', {cause: "something" } )`. However, Chrome will not automatically show the 'cause' when you throw that.
`try{ throw new Error ('message', {cause: "something" }) }catch(e){ console.log(e ) }`. You can manually show it, though:
`try{ throw new Error ('message', {cause: "something" }) }catch(e){ console.log(e, e.cause ) }`. Also note the browser support: it's only for newer browsers.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try something like this

`throw new Error('Uh oh:', console.error(spaghetti_o))`
?

Comment: _"The Error version generally does a crappy job of formatting the objects and arrays"_ -- the `Error` object is not responsible for the error message it receives as argument. Your code creates it. Try ``console.log(`Uh oh: ${spaghettio}`)`` and you'll see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Combining `console.error` with `throw new Error` is probably shortest way to achieve what you want (please notice that you won't be able to expand object in StackOverflow console, it will be fully printed here):

```js
const spaghettio = {sauce: 'arrabiata', cheese: 'gorgonzola'}
throw new Error(console.error('Uh oh:', spaghettio))
```

Comment: `console.error` doesn't return anything. Why do it this way?

Comment: As far as I understand OP wants to rise exception and have features of `console.error` to pretty print some kind of object. In this case he will get both in 1 lane (of course you could extract this `console.error` line below/above and get pretty much same result). The only downfall of this approach is double entries (pretty printed object along with message and empty exception with it's features) in logs. I agree it's not "clean" approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own errors and then create custom handling, which can include i.e. objects:

```js
class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(message, obj) {
        super(message);
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}

async function x() {
    throw new MyError('ab', { that: 'is', much: { really: 'weird' } });
}

x().catch(err => {
    if (err instanceof MyError) {
        console.error(err.message);
        console.error(err.obj);
    }
})
```